# Avoiding Redos Attacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Using regular expressions is a little bit tricky especially in Node.js applications. Because It can cause REDOS attacks. I thought that maybe running all regular expression matches in another thread than the event loop. But I am not sure that it is a good practice or not. Could you help to identify that if I run all matches in another thread, It will be able to help me to avoid this kind of attack?

Comment: Shouldn't you rather prevent random users from being able to make your server execute overly complicated regex? Why do you need to accept generic regexs from users, shouldn't that be the focus?

Comment: The problem is, if you are using regex, you can write vulnerable regexes too. (It is not required to be written by the user for being vulnerable)

Comment: a) it's not like it's terribly common to "accidentally write a regex that happens to be a worst-case for a well-tested regex engine" (you also won't say "i cant use hashmaps, because hash collision 'attacks' may just happen by chance for my input" - ok, probably less likely by orders of magnitude, but it's a similar idea). b) If something like that were to happen, wouldn't you rather focus on fixing the regex? Are you in some place, where lots of well funded and experienced hackers are set out to REDOS attack you from every angle, and a single failure is catastrophic?

Comment: What *specific* problem are you trying to solve? What is three specific usecase in your specific app where this is a danger?

Comment: What i am saying is, accidentally writing such a regex in addition to a "worst case input" for it, is so rare (additionally so, if you even know of the issue), that unless you are writing really operationally critical code, i would just not get too big a headache about the situation, happily code, and should it happen (likely never will), find it in a debugger, and fix it.

Comment: Actually, we are living on Earth where experienced hackers live. I wanted to clarify how experienced developers avoid this problem. As I understood, the only way is to improve my regex.

Comment: Sure, there are probably methods to be even more secure. You probably won't find anyone using such methods though, unless they work on a stock exchange daytrade bot, moving millions of dollars a day. Also, as mentioned before, if you don't accept regex/input pairs in some way from users, then it's hard for hackers to put their malicious regex anywhere. Also, if it were to happen, it's not like it extracts data, it just slows/crashes your server. It's similar to some well amplified DDoS, it's annoying (very much so), but usually doesn't cause permanent damage.

Comment: I started to think about this, after watching a video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lfbFEZ0jII&t=126s). It is a video about regex vulnerability on ms js library(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms) which has 50,000,000 weekly downloads. I want to create a library to solve this problem for all regexes (even if the user gives you a regex or you are using vulnerable regex). But I am not sure how to solve this. I understood your point, thanks for your response to my question.

Comment: Or validate input in other ways first, or... Without knowing what *specifically* you're trying to avoid it's impossible to help. SO isn't for general questions--for that you'd be better off in a security group or https://security.stackexchange.com/ or just searching the material already available.

Comment: I have come across this question too. In some cases I decided to only allow shell-style wildcards, which can easily be converted to a regex for an actual search.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid ReDOS by using atomic groups and possessive quantifiers.

While these features are not supported natively in JS (there is a [proposal](https://github.com/rbuckton/proposal-regexp-atomic-operators) pending), you can emulate them by using the [`/(?=(...))\1/` pattern](https://javascript.info/regexp-catastrophic-backtracking#lookahead-to-the-rescue) around the bit that would otherwise backtrack. That pattern means that whatever `\1` matches will be set in stone for this parse, since the JS RegExp engines won't backtrack into look ahead assertions (`/(?=...)/`), per spec.

Adding visual noise to an already complex RegExp may not be everyone's cup of tea though, and in that case, you may want to use a library like [`compose-regrexp`](https://github.com/pygy/compose-regexp.js#readme) that provides an `atomic()` helper that can be composed with other RegExp-building functions:

```
import {atomic, sequence} from 'compose-regexp'

// classic ReDOS-vulnerable RegExp:
const ReDOS = /^(([a-z])+.)+[A-Z]([a-z])+$/

// fixed with compose-regexp, this does not backtrack
const fixed = sequence(/^/, atomic(/(([a-z])+.)+/), /[A-Z]([a-z])+$/)
```

You can see it in action [here](https://flems.io/#0=N4Igxg9gdgzhA2BTEAucD4EMAONEBMQAaEAMwEskZUBtUKTAW2TQDoALAF0fmPSk6IBqECAC+RekxYhWAK2olIAoZxHlG2CACdOAAmCZOERuTBE9eAI4BXIWERi9pbSb0BySJoh4AtNsQAc0QAD2wAAQAGVgA2Vkj3AB0oZIB6VL0AMXIQ8ihAvQAlRAARAHkAZT0Ad3JOdj0vLT8A4LDk5Rh9YvKqgF49VIA9AAoRmkxfAC8AXQBKAGpWRZoAQV8ALRnxydnFgBJU5LSMgDkIQT16oxrtHGw8gvrEGvYEF+LAgFEwmogbeD4KDufTVHQAaws0EQJz07EwMCuEEsjyQen++meemwmF0V3h+gARpgwODOHdSYjMFB8HpyHAsIJYXU6VA9NT2cZTGARnNGph4PBWB1oF1nDkCHoBtY7FAHCNhqkLEYTGYFWMJtN5ktFqk5hZUmtNttNXsFoc5sc5aLMRoXgMRlhCYh4BZSHy+gA+AzJPSNUXvVicO2OzDO+CWtn+2CB+AQQIjUi8yN+zqB4PML400PhyNiK2dTGILo9SpSvQhKXejOIEaJECFL69FB6esLEIWXle0sVIPFzgjEJzSOFq797IhSUDSteq4h+sUSf4Fttjt6LuexcEPtdQfDq3pMDsRCk-EvABCrmqeG00YZiDdSEYiPwEGLwP0+Hp2CwAE87+mdrYq42CINo8C-skABuEDkLSNC+q2ICYChqFoehGGoQAhPWRCIfWmGEURmA4cQ+HIcRlFoaReFRgRVEMSRuHkYxjGkckMysKQOhfCS7AjDAXrAIIJalJUAlzAA3GOXQTgQEliJGyR8HgSBgMGooiJEKAAKwAEziJIIAMMwIisGAMCKPwgjCGg4gzGIQA).